# req.user is unidentified in session (Node, express, session, passport)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, passport.js

For some reason req.user is undefined, and after 4+ hours of trying to figure out why, I'm asking here. I even copy-pasted the server/index.js file of a friend's server, changed the auth strategy so it worked for mine, and I get the same issue.

Everything else is working. It redirects to auth0, comes back to the correct place, either creates a new user in the DB or finds the user. In passport.serializeUser it has all the data I passed along. But when I hit the '/auth/me' endpoint, req.user is undefined.

server/index.js

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors')
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require('passport');
const Auth0Strategy = require('passport-auth0');
const massive = require('massive');
const axios = require('axios');
const process = require("process");
const moment = require('moment');

const app = express();

//app.use(express.static(__dirname + './../build'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET, 
    cookie: { maxAge: 60000 },
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
   }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); 

// Use the session middleware
massive(process.env.CONNECTION_STRING)
.then( (db) => {
    console.log('Connected to Heroku')
    app.set('db', db);
}).catch(err=>console.log(err))
 


passport.use(new Auth0Strategy({
    domain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
    clientID: process.env.AUTH_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: process.env.AUTH_CALLBACK
}, (accessToken, refreshToken, extraParams, profile, done) => {
    const db = app.get("db");
    const userData = profile._json;

    db.find_user([userData.identities[0].user_id]).then(user => {
    if (user[0]) {
        return done(null, user[0]);
    } else {
        db.create_user([
            userData.given_name,
            userData.family_name,
            userData.email,
            userData.identities[0].user_id
        ])
        .then(user => {
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
    });
}))

passport.serializeUser( (user, done) => {
    //console.log('serializeuser', user)
    done(null, user);
}) 

passport.deserializeUser( (id, done) => {
    app.get("db").find_session_user([id])
        .then(user => {
        console.log(user);
        done(null, user[0]);
        });
})

app.get('/auth', passport.authenticate('auth0'));
app.get('/auth/callback', passport.authenticate('auth0', {
    successRedirect: process.env.SUCCESS_REDIRECT
}))

app.get('/auth/me', (req, res) => {
    console.log('auth/me endpoint hit')
    console.log(req.user)
    if(!req.user){
        return res.status(401).send('No user logged in.');
    }
    return res.status(200).send(req.user);
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port: ${process.env.PORT}`));
```

server/.env

```js
CONNECTION_STRING=postgres:*****
SECRET=*******
AUTH_DOMAIN=****.auth0.com
AUTH_CLIENT_ID=***
AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET=***
AUTH_CALLBACK=http://localhost:8084/auth/callback
SUCCESS_REDIRECT=http://localhost:3000/
PORT=8084
```

Comment: `const userData = profile._json;` try to console.log(profile._json) to begin

Comment: That's a lot of code to post with a very general question. Try reducing your code set to the minimal snippet that can recreate the problem. And/or, add debugging info to pinpoint the spot where your expectations are not being met and post that. (Most likely, you'll find your answer in that process. If you do, please post the solution for others to learn from!)

Comment: The auth strategy part is working fine. If I clg profile._json I get all the right data back. 

The problem lies in the app.get('/auth/me'... endpoint. req.user is undefined, but from everything I have learned and searched it shouldn't be. I think the issue is stemming from something further up in the code, but I don't know where. Which is why I shared the whole server/index.js file

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `app.get('/auth', passport.authenticate('auth0'));` line after the `app.get('/auth/me', (req, res) => {` block.  app.get can do regex matches and goes with the first one that matches (http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#path-examples), and I think it's trying to run the /auth logic for the /auth/me path.

Comment: The app.get('/auth/me'... endpoint is getting hit correctly. I have two console logs in that endpoint. The first just says "auth/me endpoint hit", the second is just trying to console log req.user, which always says undefined.
So my console looks like: 
"auth/me endpoint hit
undefined"